# Is 'be to verb' the only case of

Tags: grammar, formality

any construct getting formal when they get shorter? Normally, when you shorten a phrase, then they feel like informal or colloquial. I heard that 'be to' construct is the short form of 'be going to' in somewhere else. So I was wondering if there's any example of this kind of transition.

Comment: Can you give an example of "be to ___" used in this way?

Comment: The Prime Minister is to visit Budapest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, several.

Two examples:

*Have you any?* is old-fashioned or literary. Everyday versions are *Have you got any?* and *Do you have any?*

*Had he seen it, ...* is formal/literary for *If he had seen it, ...*.

Comment: Looking at it again, it seems I misunderstood the focus of the question when I posted my own answer. It's actually asking for *more examples* of contexts where shorter verb forms (i.e. - *without* any auxiliary verb), rather than the meaning of the specific verb choice made in the example. But what I'd like to know now is whether there are (were?) any syntactic or semantic constraints on *which specific verbs* can be / could have been credibly inverted in questions. It seems to me that ***Know / Knew** you my brother?* were once fine, but ***Seen** you my brother?* just sounds totally weird.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica _Saw you my brother?_ is, or was, OK though. Googling "Saw you him" found Lady Capulet saying "Where is Romeo? Saw you him today?" and, from the King James Bible "Saw ye him whom my soul loveth?"

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica: _Seen you my brother?_ is indeed totally weird, because the normal form was _Saw you my brother?_

Comment: @KateBunting, Colin: Ah right. I'm *still* not firing on all four cylinders! I did actually edit my first comment to include past tense ***knew*** as well as ***know***, having realised that I was contrasting it with past tense ***seen***. But ***saw*** just didn't come to mind at the time.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Neither am I! Of course it was Lady _Montagu_ (his mother) who asked for Romeo.

Answer (score 0):

> 1: *She **is going to** be home by midnight*

...is normally a straightforward *predictive assertion* equivalent to...

> 1a: *She **will** be home by midnight*.

---

BUT...

> 2: *She **is to** be home by midnight*

...normally carries the strong implication that...

> 2a: *She **is required to** / **must** be home by midnight*

This second form is often used when the speaker himself is the person imposing the requirement / giving the order, but it can also be used where the "requirement" (to be home by midnight, or whatever) is imposed by *someone else, circumstances, "Fate", etc.*

Answer (score 0):

According to "Oxford Guide to English Grammar", the "Be to" is another way to express something in the future, like:

> The two leaders are to meet for talks on a number of issues

NOTE: Be is often left out in headlines:
The Prime Minister to visit Budapest